# Sharepoint Online, Custom Styles for Specific Page (Just content, not overall theme)

Tags: sharepoint-online, css, custom, design

Hopefully you guys can point me in the right direction, as I haven't be able to find any solid documentation on this problem I've been having.

The company I work for recently embraced Office 365, and with it, Sharepoint Online. Given the department I work in, and the many standards we follow, I figured it would be great to set up a small wiki page (with jumping navigation) dedicated to these standards.

I developed this wiki as an HTML document to begin with, thinking I could merge it into Sharepoint Online once I had everything set up. My first thought was to use a <link rel="" href="" type="" /> to pull in the CSS. Sharepoint online instructed me that I do not have the privileges required to do this. An admin attepted it, and it was merely stripped out. I moved on to using simple style tags for the CSS, and Sharepoint stripped out everything within the style tags.

Currently, I have this wiki up and running, however, it is completely styled in-line. This wouldn't be such a problem at all if the use of "wikis" were within our department only, however, other departments have shown interest in this as well. Without knowledge of HTML and CSS, they won't be able to utilize the wiki I have developed. In order for them to use it, there would have to be predetermined classes/IDs, as well as styling to go along with them. There would have to be styling for header tags, paragraph tags, list tags and the like as well, meaning a prexisting set of CSS would be required for our company to use the features I've put together.

I guess my question is this. Is there a way to call an external stylesheet and/or use style tags with custom classes and styles within the editor (using the HTML editor, not the wysiwyg editor built in) that would be used on a basic content page that has been created? Is there any way to get this to work?

Comment: Comment because it's a first post: You could make your question a bit more concise (and general) so it's not as much text to read for someone to answer.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint online 2013 introduces the Design Manager — a new interface and central hub for managing all aspects of branding your SharePoint site. This feature can be accessed from the top level site collection for SharePoint Online, once the publishing infrastructure service has been enabled.

If you need to completely redesign a site from scratch or reuse a previous design of yours, you can use the Design Manager, which lets you modify master pages, page layouts, mobile views, and more.

The Design Manager can be used to upload design assets—images, HTML, CSS, and so on.
I think it can serve your purpose.

For more details on how to work with design manager : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj822363.aspx